# Mapping address to multiple tomcat instances

Tags: apache, tomcat, hosting, ip

I have 3 tomcat instances running on Windows Server 2008 machine. Each one with one app:

- http://host:8080/app0
- http://host:8081/app1
- http://host:8082/app2

How I can configure my server to map an address without the port number?

- http://host/app0
- http://host/app1
- http://host/app2

Is it a tomcat configuration or something with DNS?

Thanks.

---

Ok, I tried the following:

- Set up the Apache 2.2
- Configure httpd.conf loading proxy modules
- And add a proxy module configuration:

  ```
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /app1 http://machine:8081/app
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://machine:8081/app

  <Location "/app">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
  ```

Now the redirect works well local in the machine. But it doesn't works when I try access from another machine in the same network. (this another machine can ping 'machine' host. And I tried putting the ip number too).

Answer (score 1):

You can use nginx (http://nginx.org/en/docs/) as proxy for example.

Try simply (no load balancing etc.):

```
    server {

    listen here.your.ip:80/YourApp;

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/webapp;
        proxy_pass http://host:8080/YourApp;
    }

}
```

Same way for other ports

Comment: Nice tip @Stugal. I'm trying to install and configure [http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy](TomcatReverseProxy). I configured one redirection from localhost/app to localhost:8080/app/, but i'm this error occurs:

**Service Temporarily Unavailable** _The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later._

When I access the target directly, it's works. When I put a target value like google.com it's works too.

Comment: There is a note on the bottom of the page http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy: *With a default Tomcat setup, you will have broken links in the Tomcat Manager page. Learn how to fix them with mod_proxy_html.* Probably it affects other pages too. I'm verifying it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to use multiple Tomcats behind Apache to do load balancing. While this is not load balancing the principle is the same. Instead of having one application with 3 load-balanced Tomcat workers, you would have 3 applications with 1 tomcat worker each.

You can find the tomcat documentation here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/

Comment: we have one tomcat installation with 3 instances because some memory leak problems. Actually we are running each instance with 1.6g of heap memory that is the maximum in a 32bits jvm. So, for while, we need separated java process. Once we have 3 instances in different ports, how to set each one with a friendly label? host/app1, host/app2 and host/app3?

Comment: So the 3 applications are in fact the same application? This was not clear form your question. In this case this really is load balancing and the browsers just connect to host/app which Apache maps to one of the Tomcats behind. The clients do not event know which tomcat serviced their request. Sticky sessions might be required depending on your application.

Comment: Yep, they are the same application. It's an application with services provided for 5 clients. But 2 of them consumes a lot of resources that causes tomcat memory leak. The immediate solution was increase the tomcat heap size memory, but it wasn't enough (because the 1.6g limit). So we decide to isolate the huge client in another tomcat process, with another 1.6 memory space and another port number. But the new tomcat instance has the address http://host:8081/app2, witch we desire to configure one alias like http://host/app2. The main goal is make http://host/app2 = http://host:8081/app2.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mod proxy configuration` on below code in `httpd`:

```
ProxyPass           /app0   http://localhost:8080/app0/
ProxyPassReverse    /app0   http://localhost:8080/app0/
ProxyPass           /app1   http://localhost:8081/app1/
ProxyPassReverse    /app1   http://localhost:8081/app1/
ProxyPass           /app2   http://localhost:8082/app2/
ProxyPassReverse    /app2   http://localhost:8082/app2/
```